# Mapping multiple columns to an array with NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, mapping, legacy

I have an old database which can't be changed and I am currently using NHibernate.
The problem is that I have a table with multiple columns and I would like to map them into a single array.

**Table**
ID
Price1
Price2
Price3
Price4
[...]

The class will be the following:

```
public class MyClass {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public decimal[] Prices { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible?
I must only read data and I don't actually need to set/save that property.
I have tried many mappings but I couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, this is only a workaround, and is pretty dirty, but I think it might work:

```
public class MyClass {
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }
  protected virtual decimal Price1 { get; set; }  
  protected virtual decimal Price2 { get; set; }  
  protected virtual decimal Price3 { get; set; }  
//...
  public decimal[] Prices 
  { get 
    {
      return new decimal[] {Price1, Price2, Price3};
    }
  }
}
```

but, there might be a more sophisticated answer using NH's mapping abilities that I don't know of.

Comment: I wouldn't call this "pretty dirty" - it's a pretty standard wrapper property.

Comment: Hi, that was my first solution but unfortunately it is not suitable since the columns may vary and I would like to change only the mapping XML and preferably not the code. Thanks anyway!

Comment: What about using a custom user type which accepts a list of columns?  It would be quite difficult to implement but maybe it should suit my needs. Anyway it seems that there are no "easy" ways to do this...

Comment: that might work. I don't think you can pass it the columns via its c'tor (since it's called internally from within NH), but you can set it up to read from some config file or some such. this is a good example to get started, if you need one- http://intellect.dk/post/Implementing-custom-types-in-nHibernate.aspx